# Do spellbooks radiate magic for Detect Magic?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, equipment

Would detect magic work on a wizards spellbook?
Is the spellbook actually magical and if so what does this entail?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Even filled with spells, a typical [spellbook](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/goods-and-services/books-paper-writing-supplies/#TOC-Spellbook) is nonmagical. [Magic item creation](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic-items/#TOC-Magic-Item-Creation) typically mandates the creator possess an item creation feat, make a Spellcraft skill check to assure the magic item's completed properly, and meet several other prerequisites, usually the triggering of one or more spells during the magic item's manufacture. Making a blank spellbook into a wizard's spellbook mandates only copying a spell (using special inks) into that previously blank spellbook. This means, for instance, the spell [*detect magic*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/detect-magic/) won't pick out a typical spellbook from among other books on a shelf.

However, creatures often protect their spellbooks with magic (e.g. [*sepia snake sigil*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/sepia-snake-sigil/)) to prevent unwanted prying or thievery. These magical effects show up upon a *detect magic* spell being used on a spellbook so protected, and, also, actual *magical* spellbooks are a thing (e.g. a [*blessed book*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/book-blessed/)).

Comment: Isn't the writing magical, kinda like a scroll but not precisely like one?

Comment: There's no relationship between a magic scroll and the spells written in a spellbook. In earlier editions, a spellbook was *almost* like a scroll—for example, in an extreme emergency, a wizard could cast a spell directly from his spellbook and that would cause the spell to vanish from his spellbook—, but those rules were removed in *3e* in favor of a spellbook being not a magical but a mechanical storage device for a wizard's spells.

Answer (score 3):

To be picked by Detect Magic, a target needs to be a magic item with caster level, or to have an active spell on it (in either case, the caster level determines the aura strength). There is no mention that spellbooks have a caster level, so they are not detected.